# Paramiko recv() works in the interactive mode but doesn't work inside script

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to read banner from one of the switch using paramiko module in python. This is the code which i am using for the same

```
import socket
import sys
import paramiko
import subprocess
a=paramiko.SSHClient()
a.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
a.connect('10.22.158.19',username='admin',password='airwave')
b=a.invoke_shell()
b.recv_ready()
b.recv(1000)
```

When I run above I am not getting any output , but when i comment last line in the script and when i execute last command in shell `b.recv(1000)` is giving actual output

```
>>> 
>>> b.recv(1000)
'Last login: Tue Aug 22 23:10:25 2017 from 10.20.14.150\r\r\n(AirwaveMM-19) [mynode] #'
>>>
```

Does anyone of you have any clue what is wrong here ?

Comment: Can you give more details about the target device and paramiko version? You see some devices implement part of SSH protocol (and thus the `invoke_shell()`). Also paramiko 2.X uses different cryptography modules. Finally, it would be very useful if you can import and enable `logging` in debug level and post the full output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
while not b.recv_ready():
    time.sleep(0.1)
print b.recv(1000)
```

The `recv_ready()` function checks if data is ready but it does not wait for the data to be ready.

Comment: I tried using recv_ready() but that didn't help      >>> paramiko.__version__
'2.2.1'
>>>

Comment: Now its working. Seems `sleep` is needed which i didnt put it in my initial code . Also `print ` is needed . Thanks for your help